# Duplicating each cell of a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and got some intro questions.

If i have a vector 
A = (1,0,1)

I would like to duplicate each cell 5 times to get

B = (1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)

Which ways are there to do it?

Comment: There are plenty of ways and this question has been asked many times before. Google this exact question and you'll get many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to replicate the vector in an additional dimension and then reshape back to the original dimension.

```
B = reshape(repmat(A,5,1),1,[])
```

Comment: @CapeCode If you repmat(A,1,5) you will get 101101101 not 111000111.